# implementing autoplay in flickity

Tags: bigcartel, flickity

I currently have a big cartel website with the Trace theme. It has a flickity
carousel on the home page.
I'd love for this to autoplay like a slideshow

I don't know much about web development  - hence the reason I have a big cartel website. I've done the odd bit of tinkering to change minor things.  It seems like it would be an easy fix for someone that knows what to do, I don't even know where to put the code. Does anyone think they could direct the blind?

I found the flicky .CSS  and all looks good with that... I like the way it is styled.

This is the code on the flickity website on the autoplay page:

```
<!-- Flickity HTML init -->
  <div class="carousel" data-flickity='{ "autoPlay": true }'>
<div class="carousel-cell"></div>
<div class="carousel-cell"></div>
<div class="carousel-cell"></div>
<div class="carousel-cell"></div>
<div class="carousel-cell"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the JS that you need.
`// external js: flickity.pkgd.js`

there is also some CSS on the flickity website, but I don't think I need that as I'm happy with how my website has the carousel styled. I can view the flickity CSS on my website.

[www.jadedseas.co.nz](http://www.jadedseas.co.nz)  to view the current slideshow.

Comment: Hi Joanne, unfortunately stackoverflow is not for hiring developers and you can ask here only programming or code questions. Can you add more programming details about your issue? What code did you "copy paste"?

If you are looking to hire someone, you might need to look https://www.freelancer.com.au/ or https://www.upwork.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hi Joanne looking at your website and the code that you have posted, you have to add  `data-flickity='{ "autoPlay": true }'` to your carousel that you want to autoplay.

So taking your website, you need to add it to the main-carousel:

```
<div class="carousel carousel-main flickity-enabled is-draggable" ADD HERE tabindex="0" style="height: 100%;">
      <div class="flickity-viewport"><div class="flickity-slider" style="left: 0px; transform: translateX(0%);"><a href="/category/necklaces" class="carousel-cell is-selected" style="position: absolute; left: 0%;">
              <div class="category-image" style="background-image:url('https://assets.bigcartel.com/product_images/266895101/DSC_3336.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;h=1000&amp;w=1000');"></div>
              
              <div class="category-name">
                <div class="category-text">
                  <div class="category-title">NECKLACES</div>
                  <div class="category-subtitle">Shop now</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
            </a><a href="/category/earrings" class="carousel-cell" style="position: absolute; left: 100%;">
              <div class="category-image" style="background-image:url('https://assets.bigcartel.com/product_images/263007329/DSC_3258.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;h=1000&amp;w=1000');"></div>
              
.
.
.
.
              </div></div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I Figured it out ~ except it doesn't work on mobile versions.  DOH!!! I'm completely lost there now - I don't even know where to start to get it to work on mobile. Even had a developer friend look at it with me and he couldn't sort.